# relation between $\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} $, and $\frac{\partial V_1}{\partial x} $ $V_1=V(x,-y)$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

let $V=V(x,y)$ and $V_1=V(x,-y)$

then what is relation between $\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} $, and   $\frac{\partial V_1}{\partial x} $

and between $\frac{\partial V}{\partial y} $ and$\frac{\partial V_1}{\partial y} $

using chain rule

$$\frac{\partial V_1}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial V1}{\partial x}.\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} +\frac{\partial V_1}{\partial (-y)} .\frac{\partial (-y)}{\partial y}   $$ now $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=0. $ gives $$ \frac{\partial V_1}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial V_1}{\partial (-y)}=-\frac{\partial V(x,-y)}{\partial (-y)}  $$

is it right up till now??  is $\frac{\partial V(x,-y)}{\partial (-y)} =\frac{\partial V}{\partial y } $???

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to make the application of the chain rule simpler. I'd like to differentiate $V_{1}$ by going through $V$. Let's introduce the helper function
$$\pi(x,y)=(x,-y)$$
$\pi$ is a differentiable map $\mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$. We have:

$$V_{1}(x,y) = V(\pi(x,y))$$
so $$V_{1} = V \circ \pi$$
and hence by the chain rule, $$dV_{1} = dV \cdot d\pi$$
or perhaps more familiarly 
$$\frac{\partial V_{1}}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial V}{\partial \pi_{1}}\frac{\partial \pi_{1}}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial \pi_{2}}\frac{\partial \pi_{2}}{\partial x}$$
where $\pi(x,y) = (\pi_{1}(x,y),\pi_{2}(x,y))$, i.e. $\pi_{1}(x,y) = x$ and $\pi_{2}(x,y) = -y$. In other words, differentiate $V$ with respect to its first argument, and multiply by how much the first argument changes with respect to $x$, and do the same for the second argument. The derivatives $\frac{\partial V}{\partial \pi_{i}}$ are evaluated at $\pi(x,y)$, while the derivatives of $\pi_{i}$ are evaluated at $(x,y)$. We have $$\frac{\partial \pi_{1}}{\partial x} = 1; \frac{\partial \pi_{2}}{\partial x} = 0$$
Therefore,

$$\frac{\partial V_{1}}{\partial x}_{(x,y)} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial \pi_{1}}_{\pi(x,y)}\frac{\partial \pi_{1}}{\partial x}_{(x,y)} \\ = \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}_{(x,-y)}$$

Similarly, $$\frac{\partial V_{1}}{\partial y}_{(x,y)}=\frac{\partial V}{\partial \pi_{1}}_{\pi(x,y)}\frac{\partial \pi_{1}}{\partial y}_{(x,y)} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial \pi_{2}}_{\pi(x,y)}\frac{\partial \pi_{2}}{\partial y}_{(x,y)} \\ = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}_{(x,-y)}$$